# Index entries with hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref, indexing

I am using `\newcommand{\Index}[1]{#1\index{#1}}` to add my index entries.  However, I am not sure how I can have something like `\Index{\href{index entry}{http://www.blahblah.com}}` and `\Index{\href{index entry2}{http://www.blahblah2.com}}` etc.

Comment: `\protect\href{....}`

Comment: @Christian Hupfer.  Thank you.  It works.  How can I mark the answer accepted?

Comment: Reza: I posted a full answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's necessary to use `\protect\href{}` and most of the `hyperref` macros in conjunction with `\index`, e.g. like in this answer of mine here:

[Linking indexed term to index entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275522/linking-indexed-term-to-index-entry/275556#275556)